# How to trim a string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this alphabet: {'faa','fa','af'}
and I have this string: "faaf"

I have this regex: "(faa|fa|af)*" which helps me match the string with the alphabet.

How do I make Java trim my string into: {fa,af}, which is the correct way to write the string: "faaf" based on my alphabet?

here is my code:

```
        String regex = "(faa|fa|af)*";
        String str = "faaf";
        boolean isMatch = Pattern.matches(regex, str);
        if(isMatch)
        {
          //trim the string
            while(str.length()!=0)
            {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(faa|fa|af)(faa|fa|af)*$");
                Matcher mc = pattern.matcher(str);
                if (mc.find())
                {
                     String l =mc.group(1);
                     alphabet.add(l);
                     str = str.substring(l.length());
                     System.out.println("\n"+ l);

                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks to Aaron who helped me with this problem.

Comment: I think you could just add anchors to your regex and let the regex engine work out which combination matches the whole text

Comment: My code above does that. What I want is the letters concatenated to generate the word

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea, but you could match `^(faa|fa|af)(faa|fa|af)*$`, add the first group to the list of tokens, remove it from the input string and return to step 1 with the shortened input until it is empty

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Aaron! you made my day.

Comment: You're welcome ! I'm saying it's not such a good idea, because it "backtracks" after every token, while you would only need to backtrack on ambiguous tokens, so it's execution is inefficient. Now if you consider the work you'd have to do to make your own parser, it's probably one of the most efficient solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex + "*");
LinkedList<String> parts = new LinkedList<>();
while (!str.isEmpty()) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (!m.matches()) { // In the first loop step.
        break;
    }
    parts.addFirst(m.group(1)); // The last repetition matching group.
    str = str.substring(0, m.start(1));
}
String result = parts.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
```

This utilizes that a match `(X)+` will yield in `m.group(1)` the last occurrence's value of X.

Unfortunately the regex module does not provide a bored-open `matches`, such as the overloaded `replaceAll` with a lambda working on a single MatchResult.

Note that `matches` applies to the *entire* string.